# How can I run a specific 'thread group' in a JMeter 'test plan' from the command line?

Tags: jmeter

How can I run a specific thread group in a Test Plan from the command line?  I have a Test Plan (project file) that contains two "thread groups": one for crawling a site and another for calling specific urls with parameters.   From the command line I execute with Maven, like so:

> mvn.bat -Dnamescsv=src/test/resources/RandomLastNames.csv
>   -Ddomainhost=stgweb.domain.com -Dcrawlerthreads=2 -Dcrawlerloopcount=10 -Dsearchthreads=5 -Dsearchloopcount=5 -Dresultscsv=JmeterResults.csv clean test verify

I want to pass an argument to run only one of the two "thread group" in that project file.   Can you do that with JMeter?   I don't want to use an IF controller unless I have to because it feels like a "hack".   I know that SoapUI lets you do this with the '-s' option.

I asked this question [on the JMeter forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ptgram24/L-jplC8ppoQ) also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our tests we use the while controller. It doesn't look like a hack to me and works well. You can turn thread groups on and off easily with the JMeter properties. Note you can't change its status when the test is already running though.

1. Add While controller - ${__P(threadActive)}
2. Set JMeter property on JMeter load ( -JthreadActive = true )
3. Run test

Please note ${__P(threadActive)} equates to ${__P(threadActive)} == true, anything other than true will result in that thread group not running

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.   That is the sort of thing I as suspected I would have to do.  A while works better than a for.  Thanks for the tip.